# Running Flask app on Windows raises "an operation was attempted on something that is not a socket"

Tags: python, flask

When running a basic Flask app I am getting this error in the shell  and can't find how to solve this.

```
 Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit) <br/>
 Restarting with stat<br/>
 Debugger is active!<br/>
 Debugger pin code: 295-257-376<br/>
Exception in thread Thread-1:<br/>
Traceback (most recent call last):<br/>
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\threading.py", line 923, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()<br/>
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\threading.py", line 871, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs) <br/>
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\serving.py", line 656, in inner
    fd=fd)<br/>
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\serving.py", line 550, in make_server
    passthrough_errors, ssl_context, fd=fd)<br/>
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\serving.py", line 462, in __init__
    socket.SOCK_STREAM)<br/>
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\socket.py", line 446, in fromfd
    nfd = dup(fd)<br/>
OSError: [WinError 10038] An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket
```

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def main():
    return render_template('main.html')

app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: Do you still have the error after turning off your firewall (as a test)?

Comment: It's didn't worked out even turning off the firewalls. The error is same as above.

Comment: Well, the underlying cause of this is that it's trying to open a file handle as a socket, which Windows doesn't support. That it's trying to do that doesn't seem to make much sense, though.

Comment: Are you running this script as the Admin user? Because your Python installation is in the Admin users's account

Comment: I tried runnng it as an admin but it doesn't worked out.

Comment: i have the same error, anyone who has figured out how to solve it?

Comment: Almost 7 years later the error persists. Has anyone ever found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

You're currently trying to execute this from a global python installation. It is a "good practice" to use virtual environments for python projects to keep each projects' pip install separate.

Start by running `pip install virtualenv`

Then, navigate to your projects folder and execute `virtualenv example-virtual-env`. This will create a new folder with its own python and pip installation. (It supports virtual environments for Python 3 as well.)

Now in shell, execute `<projects_folder>\Scripts\activate` which activates your virtual environment. Now every `pip install` you execute will be within this environment (Note the environment name before your shell cursor.)

In here, run your `pip install flask` and run your flask application.

If you're still experiencing the issue, try running CMD in administrator mode.

Comment: I tried creating virtual env  earlier too and running the flask app as admin  but it didn't solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

i know it is not a solution to the core problem, but for me the issue only occurs when setting the debug flag to True. If you can use your app without the debug/reloading features you might want to give it a try:

```
app.run(debug=False)
```

Meanwhile i am too searching for a way to actually use the debug mode on windows.